# SQL to find next greater records for each element

Tags: sqlite

I've got a table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE event (t REAL, event TEXT, value);
```

For each record in the table which have `event='type'` and `value='G'` there will be two corresponding records with `event='Z'` - one with `value=1` and one with `value=0`. Here is an example:

```
t              |  event    |  value
1624838448.123 |   type    |    G
1624838448.123 |    Z      |    1
1624839543.215 |    Z      |    0
```

Note that there could be other `event='Z'` records that don't have corresponding `type='G'` records.   I'm trying to write a query to find all the `event='G'` records that *do* have a corresponding `type='G'` record to use as the bounds for an additional query (or join?).

Note: The t value for the "type" event and the Z event where value=1 will always be the same.

So for instance if the table looked like this:

```
t              |  event    |  value
1624838448.123 |   type    |    G
1624838448.123 |    Z      |    1
1624839543.215 |    Z      |    0
1624839555.555 |   type    |    H
1624838555.555 |    Z      |    1
1624839602.487 |    Z      |    0
1624839999.385 |   type    |    G
1624839999.385 |    Z      |    1
1624840141.006 |    Z      |    0
```

Then I want the results of the query to return this:

```
t1             |       t2
1624838448.123 | 1624839543.215
1624839999.385 | 1624840141.006
```

Comment: *...find all the event='G'* do you mean value='G'? Edit your question and explain better what you want and post expected results also.

Comment: Is it just the sequence of rows in the table that differentiates the Z-0 values. In other words, how do you know that 1624840141.006 (Z-0) belongs with 1624839999.385? (And not with some earlier type/G record?

Comment: @wwkudu There are always three records (ignoring any other events in between) in chronological order: the "type" event, the first "Z" record with the same timestamp, and the second "Z" record with a later timestamp.  There will never be another "type" event with value "G" in between the event "Z", value=1 and event "Z", value=0.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> There are always three records (ignoring any other events in between)
> in chronological order: the "type" event, the first "Z" record with
> the **same** timestamp, and the second "Z" record with a later timestamp

So, there is no need to return `t1` separately since it is equal to `t` in the row where `event = 'type'` and `value = 'G'`.

For `t2` you can use conditional aggregation with `MIN()` window function:

```
SELECT t1, t2 
FROM ( 
  SELECT t AS t1, event, value
         MIN(CASE WHEN event = 'Z' AND value = '0' THEN t END) OVER (ORDER BY t ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) t2
  FROM Event
)
WHERE event = 'type' AND value = 'G'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=09c996993e488046e50ed239ae40ea9a).

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution using the RANK() function.  With this I get an intermediate table which has the same rank for both the "type" and first "Z" record, since they have the same timestamp, and a rank two greater for the second "Z" record.  I use `WITH` so I can self join repeatedly without having to specify the same query over and over. I first join the "type" and first "Z" row by requiring that the type of two second record be greater than that of the first (so I only get the type:Z combination and not type:type, Z:type, or Z:Z).  Then I self join again to get the rank-2 row which picks up the second Z record.  Overall, the query looks like this:

```
WITH Seq(t,event,A,I)
AS
(
    SELECT t, event, value,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t) I
    FROM Event e1
    WHERE (e1.event='type' OR e1.event='Z')
)
SELECT s2.t,s3.t
FROM Seq s1
INNER JOIN Seq s2 ON s1.I = s2.I AND s1.event < s2.event
INNER JOIN Seq s3 ON s1.I = s3.I-2
WHERE s1.value='G';
```

Comment: For this sample data, your query does not return results: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3090c5792fe901224957cc4f08e21147 (I changed WHERE s1.value='G' to WHERE s1.A='G' because the CTE does not return a column value).

Comment: @forpas Hmm, that's odd... I'll have to go back when I get some time and review my transcription from my query (which works but is a bit more complex than my simplified example)